# Why is the Einstein Static Universe an infinite cylinder?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

The Einstein static universe metric is 
$$ds^2=-dt^2 + d\chi^2 + \sin(\chi)^2d\Omega^2$$
where $-\infty<t<\infty$ , $0<\chi<\pi$ and $d\Omega^2$ is the metric on a $S^2$. It describes the topology of $R\times S^3$. Suppressing the $S^2$ coordinates, why is it always represented as an infinite cylinder if $\chi$ only goes from $0$ to $\pi$? to be a cylinder is would have to have some periodicity $\phi \sim \phi + 2\pi$. Shouldn't it just be half an infinite cylinder (i.e. just a rectangle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "vertical" axis of the infinite cylinder is designated by $t$, which goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.  The variable $\chi$, in contrast, is one component of spherical coordinates on $\mathbb S^3$.  If we designate standard spherical coordinates on $\mathbb S^2$ by $(\phi,\theta)$ and those on $\mathbb S^3$ by $(\chi,\phi,\theta)$, then the standard round metric on $\mathbb S^2$ is
$$
d\Omega^2 = d\phi^2 + \sin(\phi)^2 d\theta^2,
$$
and the standard round metric on $\mathbb S^3$ is
$$
 d\chi^2 + \sin(\chi)^2 d\phi^2 + \sin(\chi)^2\sin(\phi)^2 d\theta^2
= d\chi^2 + \sin(\chi)^2 d\Omega^2.
$$
The variable $\chi$ only goes from $0$ to $\pi$ because it represents the angle downward from the "north pole" of $\mathbb S^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question however was another (sorry if I phrased it poorly). The literature always represent this space by an infinite cylinder where every point is a $S^2$. But it seems to me that a cylinder would be a double covering because the actual range of $\chi$ is $0$ to $\pi$ whereas a cylinder would have $\chi$ to go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ where the end points are identified. So it seems the cylinder contains 2 copies of the Einstein static universe.

Comment: Here a picture to visualise (they use $r'$ instead of $\chi$): https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alberto_Rozas-Fernandez/publication/267338977/figure/fig1/AS:295687481774090@1447508797819/Fig-2-The-flat-FRW-spacetime-filled-with-a-k-essential-scalar-field-is-conformal-to-the.png

Comment: That picture is not meant to be taken too literally. In particular, it's not true that each point of the 2d cylinder represents a copy of $S^2$. A more accurate way to read the diagram is that every horizontal circle represents a copy of $S^3$. In each of those horizontal circles, the points where $\chi=0$ and $\chi=\pi$ each represent single points (the north & south poles of $S^3$). If $0<\chi<\pi$, then the pair of points $\{\pm\chi\}$ (which is a copy of $S^0$) stands in for a copy of $S^2$.